# AIX Ksh adding 0 to single or double digits to become 3 digits

Tags: ksh, aix

I have this script that gives me this exact output that I need:

Example of the output of my File:

```
    2222001 1.TEST1.1
    2222002 1.TEST1.2
    2222003 1.TEST1.3
    2825666 1.TEST1.13
    1654651 1.TEST1.15
    9999999 1.TEST1.360
    5121554 1.TEST1.100
```

What I want to do is if the digit is single add double zero before, Ex: 001,002 instead of 1,2 and if it's double add only 1 extra zero before, ex: 013,015.

so they are maximum 3 digits.

**Expected output:**

```
    2222001 1.TEST1.001
    2222002 1.TEST1.002
    2222003 1.TEST1.003
    2825666 1.TEST1.013
    1654651 1.TEST1.015
    9999999 1.TEST1.360
    5121554 1.TEST1.100
```

How can I do that in AIX Ksh?

Comment: If your question is specifically about AIX, do not tag Linux. If your question is specifically about ksh, do not tag bash.

Comment: (The way I would do this with bash -- with `[[ $str =~ $regex ]]` and `$BASH_REMATCH` -- does not work on ksh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would pipe through:

```
awk -F. -v OFS=. '$NF = sprintf("%03d",$NF)'
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways to do this would be to use a `case` statement to recognize words with one or two characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
while IFS="${IFS}." read -r word1 word2 word3 word4; do
  case $word4 in
    ?)  word4="00$word4";;
    ??) word4="0$word4";;
  esac
  printf '%s %s.%s.%s\n' "$word1" "$word2" "$word3" "$word4"
done
```

Another would be to use a format string with `%03d` to pad out with `0`s to 3 decimals:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
while IFS="${IFS}." read -r word1 word2 word3 word4; do
  printf '%s %s.%s.%03d\n' "$word1" "$word2" "$word3" "$word4"
done
```